# SQL Server MM-DD-YY convert and order by not working as planned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, grid, sql-order-by

Below is my SQL statement, I converted for the due date to display as '01/02/2019' which works in a table.

Now, when I orderby DueDate its showing 2019 first and then 2018 or by month if I use ASC not year.

I already tried `CAST`, I just want it to sort correctly.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DueDate, 101)
```

Current output:

```
01/24/2019
01/30/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/06/2019
02/07/2019
03/04/2018
03/05/2019
08/08/2018
09/04/2018
09/12/2018
09/17/2018
```

Expected output:

```
3/4/2018
8/8/2018
9/4/2018
9/12/2018
9/17/2018
1/24/2019
1/30/2019
2/1/2019
2/1/2019
2/1/2019
2/6/2019
2/7/2019
3/5/2019
```

Comment: Hint:  `order by DueDate`.

Comment: What is your full query and table definition?

Comment: You're doing a string sort, so its correctly ordering by the ascii values of the string. Leave it as a date for sorting as Gordon says above.

Comment: @DaleBurrell If i leave it as a date its showing yyyy-mm-dd 
How can i have mm-dd-yyyy and still be able to sort the correct way?

Comment: Show your query and table definition. So we can check the datatype and whether you have an alias hiding the base column.

Comment: You can still select the formatted version of the string while ordering by the date column. They are 2 separate things. `select convert(varchar,DueDate,101) from table order by Duedate ASC`

Comment: @MartinSmith
Select convert(date,DueDate,101) from table
order by Duedate ASC

Comment: or you can use `order by <alias _for_conversion>` else ` `duedate` as by the above comments correctly identified

Comment: When @MartinSmith daid give your DDL or table definition, he means the `create table` statement with all columns and data types.

Comment: @scsimon Thanks!

Comment: @Martin DueDate(datetime,null) datatype

Comment: Why have you tagged this "grid"? Is there a client component involved that is sorting the results?

Comment: @MartinSmith I think i may not be clear here , but i'll try ..if i call this table and click sort in gridvew (Visual studio) the sorting doesn't work. so, i wanted to make sure  the datatype and the sorting works in SQL in turn displaying correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your query is sorting using a character based data type.  If you want to display a formatted date string but sort by dates, then you can use something like this:

```
select convert(varchar,DueDate,101) TheDate
from MyTable
order by convert(datetime,DueDate)
```

Depending on the data type of the `DueDate` field, one of the casts may not be necessary.  Check the underlying data type of the field in your table.